# Send MP3 frames via RTP

Tags: mp3, rtp

I've written code in Delphi/Pascal to encode PCM to MP3 via LAME_ENC.DLL and send each MP3 frame via RTP (UDP) but I cannot get VLC to play it. The encoding code works as I can save the data to a file and that plays.

I have a 12 byte RTP header being sent before every frame. The Payload is set to 14. The Sequence and TimeStamp is Big Endian encoded as required. I cannot find exactly how to calculate the TimeStamp. Documentation I can find just says something about 90,000hz. Is that to be multiplied by the time in milliseconds?  Each frame is 26.1ms.

VLC just reports problems like like the following.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Many thanks.

```
mpegaudio debug: free bitrate mode
mpegaudio debug: frame too big 1953 > 1952 (emulated startcode ?)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: free bitrate mode
mpegaudio debug: frame too big 4181 > 4180 (emulated startcode ?)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
mpegaudio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out an extra 4 bytes of nulls are required after the RTP header and before the MP3 frame starts. All working nicely now.